# Connecting Django to IBM via DB2 ODBC Driver issue

Tags: python, django, db2

I'm making my first steps with Django (and Python) development and I'm still struggling with the tutorial. The back end database I'm using is DB2 (installed on Windows Sever 2008), I am connecting to it from my Windows 7 Professional machine using IBM DB2 ODBC Driver. The database name is POLLS, the ALIAS is POLLS and the System DSN Name is ... well, also POLLS.

This is the DATABASES section from the settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE'    : 'ibm_db_django',
        'NAME'      : 'POLLS',
        'USER'      : '********',
        'PASSWORD'  : '********',
        'HOST'      : 'xxxxxxx',
        'PORT'      : '50000',
        'PCONNECT'  : True,
    }
}
```

The problem I have encountered when running the 'manage runserver' command with this configuration:

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1042C  An
>   unexpected system error occurred.  SQLSTATE=58004\r SQL CODE=-1042

Running 'manage migrate' resulted in the same error.

Then after playing with the DB2 connection string I found that replacing 'NAME' by 'DBALIAS'

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE'    : 'ibm_db_django',
        'DBALIAS'   : 'POLLS',
        'USER'      : '********',
        'PASSWORD'  : '********',
        'HOST'      : 'xxxxxxx',
        'PORT'      : '50000',
        'AUTHENTICATION' : 'SERVER',
        'PCONNECT'  : True,
    }
}
```

allows me to run server without a problem, but an attempt to create tables with 'manage migrate' results in:

> File
>   "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\ibm_db_django-1.0.9.2-py3.4.egg\ibm_db_django\base.py",
>   line 212, in get_connection_params
>       raise ImproperlyConfigured( "Please specify the valid database Name to connect to" )

Comment: What tutorial did you follow, was it this one? http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.python.doc/doc/t0060891.html

Comment: I was actually following the tutorial from the djangoproject site (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01) but when working through the "Database Setup" part I was following these instructions, yes.

Comment: Hey, did you succed on connecting to DB2?

Comment: @Syafiqur__  Nope...

Comment: @Iskander Did you try using the option `--database polls` to the `python manage.py migrate` command?  Maybe edit your question to include exactly the product-name (and fixpack) of your Db2-product on the Win7 workstation(output of db2level command), and also if/how exactly you catalogued the remote-database, and how you configured the db2cli.ini and/or db2dsdriver.cfg on the Win7 workstation. ALSO please state the exact version of your django in your question. Please don't put new facts in a comment.